# CICS Program USE count being incremented but the program debug logic does not appear

Tags: cobol, mainframe, cics

I have a CICS program which reads a TD Queue and makes few  file updates.  The program is not working correctly and in my investigation I used `CEMT I PROG(XXXXXXX)`.  The output shows that USE Count is 10 for my module (USE Count is the USE Attribute as in the Picture).

The Queue is being Read and the USE count is getting incremented for every input Request but the updating of the mainframe files is not happening.

I initiated debugging using DISPLAY Statements in the code to see if the module is being triggered or not.  We are using standalone CICS Region and I have Not seen, even the first Display in the CICS MSGUSR log.

I suspect that Module is not being invoked though the USE Count is incrementing. And I have pointed the Load to PROD where we have correct code.

Is it possible a scenarios where USE count of the module is being incremented but the module is not not being executed?

[image]

Comment: please show your code, or if that's proprietary  an example code that reproduces the behavior.

Comment: If the count is updated on each request then I would suspect your logic is faulty and not the Use Count.  Have you tried debugging the code and what are you seeing ?